# Adding 2 buttons to link to 2 different activities in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-button

I'm working on a app in Android Studio with multiple activities, and I am trying to make button1 go to my ***SecondActivity*** and button2 to my ***ThirdActivity***. Whenever I run button in my app it crashes.

This is my **MainActivity.java:**

```
package hobby_pc.medispeak;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToSecondActivity();
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToThirdActivity();
        }
    });


        }
private void goToSecondActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
private void goToThirdActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

This is my **activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="hobby_pc.medispeak.MainActivity"
android:background="#ffffff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Welkom"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Medicijnenzoeken"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Goochempie"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my **AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hobby_pc.medispeak">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.Medispeak.androidsplashscreenexample.MAINACTIVITY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
</application>
```

This is the error I get when it crashes:

```
06-02 14:13:25.900 21384-21384/hobby_pc.medispeak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: hobby_pc.medispeak, PID: 21384
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hobby_pc.medispeak/hobby_pc.medispeak.ThirdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at hobby_pc.medispeak.ThirdActivity.onCreate(ThirdActivity.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: where is your ThirdActivity in manifest?

Comment: you have not added Third activity in menifest file

Comment: and your are post code of `main_activity.xml` and inflating `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Don't use the activity tag for receivers.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Comment: Future note: if your app crashes, please provide the logcat in your question.

Comment: I changed all the things you guys said but it still crashes.
and added the error in the question.

Comment: Have you declared `ThirdActivity` in your `AndroidManifest` yet? Tell us if it worked or new bug you recieved.

Comment: Where is the code, where you make setText calls on the text view? Please provide the code and XML of the third activity.

Comment: I have pasted: <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity" /> in in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Chnage your <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity" />'and to <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" /> with your packge name like  <activity android:name="hobby_pc.medispeak.SecondActivity" />

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't declared **ThirdActivity** in your **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the crash reason in this line : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hobby_pc.medispeak/hobby_pc.medispeak.ThirdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

I think in your onCreate method in thirdActivity, you are trying to setText for a textView that is not bound to view. 
use findViewById() before calling setText() on textView

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at hobby_pc.medispeak.ThirdActivity.onCreate(ThirdActivity.java:34)
```

There's your problem, a `NullPointerException` in your `ThirdActivity` class at line 34. You have apparently called `setText()` on a `TextView` without initializing it with `findViewById(R.id.some_id)` first.